# React-Query: How to useQuery to fetch again?

Tags: reactjs, react-query

Hello I am using useQuery to verify if a bearer token stored in cookie is valid or not.

```
const getQueryService = () => {


return {
    verify: async (): Promise<AuthVerifyTokenResponse | undefined> => {
      const bearerToken = Cookies.get("bearer");
      if (!bearerToken) {
        return Promise.resolve(undefined);
      }
      try {
        const result = await authApi.tokenVerifyGet();
        return result;
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("User verify error", error);
      }
    },
  };
};

  const { data: verify, isLoading } = useQuery(
    ["verify", bearerToken],
    queryService.verify,
  );
```

and I have a useEffect in this hook which calls refreshToken() endpoint which sends refresh token in cookie and sets new bearer token in cookie after.

```
  useEffect(() => {
if (!verify) {
  refreshToken();
    }
  }, [verify]);
```

Problem is after user is logged in and authenticated, I am setting bearer token in cookie, and navigates user to landing page ('/') there are some components which will render when verify is not undefined, however it still shows undefined unless I manually refresh the page which the refetches and returns the 200 status code (not undefined).

How can I make verify to fetch again after navigation from /login to / ?

Answer (score 0):

the same way you destructure data, and isLoading from useQuery, you can also destructure refetch, which is a function that when called retriggers the query